# My information won't write to a file? - Python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python, I'm learning it at school and I've been messing around with it at home, I'd like to learn it better for when GCSE's hit just to make it easier.

I'm having an issue with the code below:

```
def takeinfo():
    print("To begin with, would you like to write your file clean? If you're making a new file, yes.")
    choice=input()
    if 'Y' or 'yes' or 'Yes' or 'YES' in choice:
        print("What would you like to write in the file? \n")
        information=input()
        writeinfo()
    else:
        exit()
def writeinfo():
    a=open('names.txt','wt')
    a.write(information)
    a.close()
takeinfo()
```

When I type 'Yes' to be taken to the writeinfo() definition, it doesn't write the information I'm asking it to because it's unassigned, even after typing something in the takeinfo() definition? Any help would be appreciated. I understand this is simple, but I've looked at other questions and I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code.

Thankyou.

Comment: try `if choice in ['Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']:`, and your `information` variable is out of scope when you try to use it in `writeinfo`, so you need to pass it to the function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other answers show good functional style (pass `information` to the `writeinfo()` function)

for completeness' sake, you *could* also use global variables.

the problem you are facing is, that the line

```
information=input()
```

(in `takeinfo()`) will assign the input to a *local* variable, that shadows the global variables of the same name.

in order to force it to the global variable, you have to explicitely mark it as such, using the `global` keyword.

### other problems

#### `input` vs `raw_input`

`input()` in python3 will just ask you to input some data.
however, in Python2 it will *evaluate* the user-data. on py2 you should therefore use `raw_input()` instead.

#### has the user selected 'yes'?

there's another problem with your evaluation of `choice` (whether to write to file or not).
the term `'Y' or 'yes' or 'Yes' or 'YES' in choice` always evaluates to true, since it is really interpreted as `('Y') or ('yes') or ('Yes') or ('YES' in choice)`, and `bool('Y')` is `True`.
instead, you should use `choice in ['Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']` to check whether `choice` is one of the items in the list.
you can further simplify this by normalizing the user answer (e.g. lower-casing it, removing trailing whitespace).

## solution

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    # py3 doesn't know raw_input
    pass

# global variable (ick!) with the data
information=""

def writeinfo():
    a=open('names.txt','wt')
    a.write(information)
    a.close()

def takeinfo():
    print("To begin with, would you like to write your file clean? If you're making a new file, yes.")
    choice=input()
    if choice.lower().strip() in ['y', 'yes']:
        print("What would you like to write in the file? \n")
        global information
        information=input()
        writeinfo()
    else:
        exit()
```

Comment: Thankyou, I had no idea about the global function until now!

Comment: it's not exactly a *function*, but rather a *keyword*. also, if you have the habit of using global variables, you should probably rethink that.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm new to python and I've been using very basic code. I haven't exactly encountered much using definitions... which is why I made this code to see how it would work

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the argument on like this:

```
def takeinfo():
    # same as before
    information=input()
    writeinfo(information)
    # else stays the same
def writeinfo(information):
    # rest remains the same...
takeinfo()
```

Or just change information into the global scope using `global`.

And a hint for you:

```
if 'Y' or 'yes' or 'Yes' or 'YES' in choice:
```

Wouldn't work as you would've expected. You can do some extensive learning to figure out why it will always be `True` even if the user inputted "No".

Answer (score 1):

```
def writeinfo():
    a=open('names.txt','wt')
    a.write(information)
    a.close()
```

the "information" needs to be passed into the writeinfo function

should be:

```
def writeinfo(information):
    a=open('names.txt','wt')
```

and above, when the function is called:

```
print("What would you like to write in the file? \n")
information=input()
writeinfo(information)
```